# Set a default path for reports in Google Analytics

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

My website home is accessed from `mysite.com/web/home#!`

Google analytics, is always reporting me in `Top Active Pages` -> `/web/home`, and I cannot see reports from paths, after `web/home`

I tried `Admin` - `Property settings` - `View settings`. And set in `Default page` the value `home`. As its shown in this [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009675). But it still, reports me `web/home`.

How can I fix this? Does it takes time to recognize this change? or should I put another value in `Default page`?

Comment: I think GA isn't happy about the hash-bang (`#`), which can be removed with `html5mode` and proper router handling

Answer (score 1):

GA does not regard things after the hash mark as part of the Url (a remnant from the time when the # indicated in-page links rather than SPAs).

This problem is so pertinent that Google has a [guide for tracking of SPAs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications) in their documentation.

The general gist is that you do virtual pageview by passing a url to the GA tracking code that does not include a hashmark, e.g.:

```
ga('set', 'page', '/path-without-hash.html');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

It would be nicer if they updated their tool to work with current technologies than requiring workarounds, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should implement it in your app.js.

```
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        $window.ga('send', 'pageview', { page: $location.url() });
    });
```